# Getting past Watir & Basic Authentication

Tags: apache, watir

BLUF: Has anyone had luck bypassing/authenticating Apache Basic Authentication?  Passing the username and password in the url string does not work.

I've looked through several questions here on SO and on blogs like WatirMelon.blog.  The problem I have is simple: watir does not use the username/password passed along the urlstring to authenticate with the website.

Code

```
browser b = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
b.goto('https://user:passwd@my.site.com/index.htm')
```

I've even tried something akin to the following:

```
browser b = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
b.goto('https://my.site.com/index.htm')
sleep 5
b.send_keys("user{TAB}passwd{ENTER}")
```

and still have not had luck.  It appears that once the basic auth window pops up, all actions halt until user input.

Does anyone have recommendations I haven't tried?

Admin notes:
* OS: Ubuntu 16.04
* Browser: Chrome (obviously)
* Watir 6

Comment: question is not clear, the given url is not getting opened. What's the problem? You can't enter the username and password?

Comment: @RAJ, I've updated the original post, thank you.

Comment: The site you mentioned is not opening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watir will pass the url string to the url bar in the browser, but that doesn't mean the website will accept it (some do, some do not).

Basic authentication is a function handled by the operating system which is outside of the scope of Selenium & Watir. The best way to deal with it is to use a proxy like BrowserMob Proxy.

Comment: I'm marking this as a possible answer...because answer to the real problem I had was much more embarrassing.

So, we reworked our how our BA worked a few weeks ago, and updated some passwords...  Guess what I forgot to update when testing?

Comment: @NateH - lol. Been there. One way or another, I'm glad it is working for you. :)